# Show only lowest (tier)price and add "price from"

Tags: category, price, tierprice

In the catagory page ,the prices are shown directly under the product name.
In my theme (SM-Market): ***left is the normal price, on the right the Lowest tier price.***

How can I show only the lowest price??

Or:  lowest price left, normal right.

Or:  hold positions and add "price from" before lowest tierprice.

Comment: can you please share your url

Answer (score 0):

Open the following file and you will find the two prices inside. Delete the one you don't want to show. Replace X in the file url with the folder name of your SM-Market template.

```
\app\design\frontend\X\X\template\catalog\category\page.phtml
```

Comment: Ther is no "page"file in this folder, just "View".